# кодировка html из windows в ubuntu 14.04

Tags: html, ubuntu, кодировка

перекинул html файлы из windows в ubuntu, открываю gedit - вижу русские буквы, запускаю html  локально в браузер, итог - кракозябры. В html файлах - charset=win-1251.
Подскажите,как решить проблему?

Answer (score 1):

Лучший способ решить проблему - использовать кодировку utf8, с ней умеют работать основные операционные системы.

Comment: Поменял - сменился вид кракозябр и всё...

Comment: @AlexeyAl надо сохранить файл в utf8 и сменить в коде на `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>`

Answer (score 1):

Способ 1
Попробуйте в браузере сменить тип кодировки. У меня, например, в Firefox нужно выбрать меню: Вид / Кодировка / Шиндовс 1251.

Способ 2.
Если gedit смог нормально показать кириллицу, то сохраните из него файл в кодировке utf-8. Делается это так -- меню: Файл / Сохранить как ...
Откроется окно сохранения файла. Внизу слева в окне "Кодировка символов" -- укажите UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

Самый лучший способ описаный например вот [тут](http://www.linuxrussia.com/2014/04/ubuntu-1404.html#glava16).

> Для исправления проблемы в консоли необходимо выполнить следующую
>   команду:  **gsettings set org.gnome.gedit.preferences.encodings
>   auto-detected "['UTF-8', 'WINDOWS-1251', 'CURRENT', 'ISO-8859-15',
>   'UTF-16']"**

Comment: После этого никаких проблем с кодировками не встречал.

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать выдержку ответа здесь, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Ответы-ссылки могут стать недействительными в случае изменения страницы, на которую дана ссылка.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку! Учтено!